# Pages flashing white in Safari on loading or reloading content unnecessarily

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, flicker, pageload

I am wondering what might be causing the page flashing white briefly when I am navigating from page to page on a website I am designing in Safari (you can see the website [here](http://salliannputman.com/index.php)).  In addition to this flashing sometimes happening, the logo and nav bar are reloading as well (fading in and out briefly) when they should stay static.  In Firefox this is what happens, but in Safari (mostly) and Chrome occasionally I am seeing flickers and reloading.  I am using this script to fade in the content div (i.e. everything below the nav bar) on non-mobile devices, but this doesn't appear to be the culprit as I have tried commenting out the script and still see the behaviour:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    if ( screen.width <= 699 ) {
    } else {
         // your script
    document.getElementById('content').style.display = "none";
    $('#content').fadeIn(1000);
    }

});
</script>-->
```

I am wondering what else I can try to get a smoother transition.  It was working fine before, but now is not for some reason.  I have a very good internet connection.

Thanks for any help,

Nick

Comment: Although I think the code is sloppy and I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve by using it, I do not see the problem you describe while using Safari.

Comment: Do you have your browser cache enabled? Perhaps images and certain files are not caching in the browser, which could cause some of these issues.  I only mention this because I do not see a problem in Safari, FireFox or Chrome.

Comment: I haven't used them, but could you [use HTML transitions](http://htmlguide.drgrog.com/alpha/pagetransitions.html)?  E.g. Pixel Fade (12)

Comment: Thanks both. It's good to know you aren't seeing any issues at your end.  Cache is enabled.

Comment: Never mind.  Looked into it and HTML transitions look to be old extensions/hacks as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not seeing the white flash although I can understand why it might be happening:  Your page is loading `#content`, then your JavaScript is hiding `#content`, then your JavaScript is making `#content` fade back in.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if ( screen.width <= 699 ) {
    } else {
         // your script
    document.getElementById('content').style.display = "none";
    $('#content').fadeIn(1000);
    }

});
```

By the way,

```
document.getElementById('content').style.display = "none";
```

...can be replaced with...

```
$('#content').css('display', 'none');
```

...which is [*"roughly equivalent"* to `.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)...

```
$('#content').hide();
```

...then combined with the next line (called chaining)...

```
$('#content').hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

But that does not solve the white flashing problem.

So why not try making `#content` hidden by default in CSS...

```
#content {
   display: none;
}
```

And simply use the JS to fade it in...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if ( screen.width <= 699 ) {

    } else {
         // your script
        $('#content').fadeIn(1000);
    }

});
```

Of course if I knew what exactly you were trying to achieve, I'd be able to make a better recommendation.

**EDIT:**

CSS:

```
#content {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 699px) {
    #content {
        display: block; 
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: I am simply trying to keep the logo and navigation bar static and have a fade in of the main content of each page so that the transition between pages is smoother.  When using the method you have described (without the conditional statement for mobiles) I was not seeing any content on mobiles other than the logo and nav bar.  So I switched to an all jQuery method.  I could switch back and put conditional comments on the display:none CSS for mobiles.  If this is the best method could you let me know how I write the conditional statement for CSS? Thanks

Comment: @Nick, you cannot really have the logo and navigation bar "static" and only change content below.  Each link loads a totally different page.  The reason it may sometimes _appear_ to be static is due to caching built into modern browsers.  When that fails, you'd see a white flash as the new file loads.  IMHO, you are adding an unnecessary level of complexity.  Mobile browsers strive to be like desktop browsers, so design a solid site for the desktop and it should look great on the mobile browser.  Otherwise, dedicated mobile sites and apps make access to your content easier on small screens.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented your suggestion.  I still have white flashing, mostly on home page, and sometimes the about page, but never on work and work subpages, using Safari.  I will keep an eye on this.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: `.hide()` is not *exactly* the same as `$('#content').css('display', 'none');`. `.hide()` also saves the previous value of `display` to revert to if/when `.show()` is called.

Comment: @MarkWilden, According to [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), it's _"**roughly equivalent** to calling `.css('display', 'none')`"_.  I've updated my answer.  But perhaps you can explain _where exactly_ this previous value is saved.  AFAIK, you don't need to "save" anything to simply toggle `display` from `none` to `block` and back again.

Comment: @Sparky672 jQuery saves the previous value of `display` internally. It has to, because there are other `display` settings beside  `inline` and `block` to which it needs to revert on `show()`.

Comment: @MarkWilden, ah yes... the jQuery Data Cache.

Answer (score 1):

you are rendering it , hiding unhiding it, yo are also mixing js selection and jquery selection ,why not use css to have it hidden.

```
//css
 #content {display:none;}
// use media query for css detect mobile
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
#content {display:block;}
}

//js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').fadeIn(1000);

});
```